# Ls factor, flow accumulation, watershade, relief in Quantum GIS 2.2

Tags: grass-gis, qgis-2

I'm a beginner quantum gis. I want to make the LS factor of 30m DEM that I have merge and set the projection in wgs 84/UTM zone 49S (EPSG ; 37249). I'm having a problem when trying to create relief and watersheds in GRASS. First, I used the function " r.shaded.relief " to create relief. Secondly, I used the function " r.watershade " to create flow accumulation . But all failed . Here are the results

[image: relief trying]

[image: watershade trying]

Any solutions?

Answer (score 2):

Here are three suggestions.

First, you should upgrade to a new version of QGIS.

For your shaded relief, QGIS has a built-in shaded relief module. You can use that to get your shaded relief raster without the need for GRASS at all. It's under the menu *Raster->Analysis->DEM*.

To calculate watersheds, I would suggest running GRASS alone, not thru the QGIS plugin. In fact version 7.0 of GRASS is now stable, (and not supported by the plugin, yet) so you'll get faster algorithms and more modules by just installing GRASS 7.0 standalone.

Begin by setting up your GRASS LOCATION and MAPSET to match UTM Zone 49S by defining the LOCATION with the EPSG code. Then import your DEM into GRASS and run the r.watersheds module.

I would point out that your threshold of 200, as appears in the above screenshot, is **very** small. 200 cells of 30x30 m is only 0.18 sq km. So you will be getting thousands of very tiny "mini" catchment areas. If your region of interest is larger than a few 100 sq.km then you will most likely want a much larger threshold.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Micha. Before I try, I would ask you some questions.

Comment: 1. What version should I use ?
2. Suppose I use GRASS. Whether the results can be imported into quantum gis? Because, I want to use it for my project: analysis of soil erosion through QGIS.
3. How many cells should I write to make a 100 square kilometer for each watershed ?

Sorry, I really don't understand and so confused about this because it is new experience for me. Therefore , I would like to learn more about GIS .

Answer (score 1):

Your main problem now is that "your raster map is in diferent zone (-49) that current region (0)". At the begining of the post, you pointed out that the projection was in wgs 84/UTM zone 49S (EPSG : 37249). This projection is wrong. The correct one is EPSG: 32749.

[image]

Afterward, assuming that your country is Indonesia, you have to click in **Set** before a new click in **Next**. Later, you can adjust your work area to dem area.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @xunlink. I'll try your solution later. I hope you can help me next time.